# Display read more link in my own page

Tags: wordpress

In the loop,i can use the function the_content() to display the post content with "read more" link,but i designed my own page,i didn't use the loop.i use the function get_posts() to get posts.So are there others ways to display the post content with "read more" link?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global $more variable to 'enable' the read more link

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        global $more;
        $more =0;
        the_content();
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i have another question, in your code there is "global $more;" in the loop,what does global here mean?I just know in the function scope we can declare a global var.

Comment: Wordpress has some WordPress-specific global variables. To access them you first need to globalize the variable with `global $variable;`

 https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

Answer (score 0):

Can create simple Read More link of your own and use `echo get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`

```
<?php
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        global $more;
        $more =0;
        echo get_the_content();
echo '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_the_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read More</a>';
    }
 ?>
```